# Locking variables for shared array in C++98 mutex

Tags: c++, c, mutex

I'm new to the idea of mutex, but require locking control between two processes for a shared array.

The only C++ tutorials I've found that made sense to me so far for understanding mutex implementation show use of `#include <mutex>`, which fails giving error: `/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the upcoming ISO C++ standard, C++0x. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x compiler options.` is there a way to do this in either simple readable non-2011-standard C or C++?

Comment: Use [`boost.thread`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/thread.html)?

Comment: Up to the new standards C11 and C++11, threads, mutexes and all that have not been part of the languages, but had been considered part of the OS. Either you use the new language features by using the proposed `-std` arguments or you use the OS features of your platform. Since you didn't tell us what that platform is, and questions asking for tools or libraries are beyond the scope of SO, there is not much we can do for you.

Comment: Thank you for explaining that it was considered "part of the OS". Now the lack of it makes much more sense. I saw the boost version, but I was hoping there was a std method that didn't require extra linking.

Comment: @ConfusedStack, you are going to get extra linking anyway, it just may not be obvious or explicit.

Comment: I understand that, it is just that in this very specific situation, I have NO control over the terminal and thus no linker options - meaning I can't explicitly link to anything. I CAN however recompile an entire library if there was an easy way to do so by some #include.

Comment: You lost me.  Even with c++11 you still have to link against the proper libs.  For instance on most posix systems you'll need -pthreads.

Comment: ***[useful reference (POSIX)](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/)*** for sharing/locking within threaded apps.

Answer (score 3):

Neither C nor C++ had any concept of multithreading before 2011. So no, there is no way to perform multiple exclusion - or for that matter have more than one thread - using only the standard language before C11 or C++11.

Comment: that's odd, I was writing multi-threaded C++ programs on Windows platform in 1999. We used "critical sections" to lock code segments. Worked well.